# Styling secondary nav bar item folder - Squarespace - Jaunt template

Tags: css, navbar, squarespace

I want to style the folder item of the secondary nav bar of this website I am designing with Jaunt template (still in progress. Password: edizioni_test): 
https://tan-perch-9lhf.squarespace.com

I want the text **ITA / FRA** to be bold. I tried to style it with this css code:

```
span.Header-nav-item.Header-nav-item--folder a { 
   font-weight:900 !important;
   color:#777777 !important;
   }

 span.Header-nav-item.Header-nav-item--folder a:hover {
   color:#cccccc !important;
 }
```

but I am ecountering this issue: when I click on the **ITA / FRA** link, this page opens:

[issue: this folder does not contain any pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WseHC.jpg)

How to fix it in order to click on the **ITA / FRA** and having it linked to the home page? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generally-suggested method to disable / turn-off the click / link on navigation folders in Squarespace on various Squarespace template is to use `pointer-events:none` on the target element. On some templates, this requires then setting `pointer-events:all` on subsequent child elements, but not in your case.

In your case, we can simply target the specific element and leave it at that (sibling elements will remain clickable). Enter **one** of the following via the CSS editor:

```
a[href='/ita-fra'] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

OR

```
.Header-nav-folder-title {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The first method above targets the link via URL and specific to that link. The second is a more general rule that will apply to other such folders you may add to the header.

Note that this doesn't prevent "tabbing" onto the target link when using the keyboard or possibly assistive technologies, though it does typically prevent "executing" the link. To fully remove the link would require use of Javascript, but as I said, the CSS-only method is generally accepted in the Squarespace community.